# Changing number of text fields, depending on drop down list choice

Tags: javascript, html, textfield, visibility

I'm trying to show two test fields after choosing "id" from drop down list. It's set on hidden and im trying to make it visible when "id" is selected. Unfortunately it's not working. Please help!

```
<form>
            <input class="hidden" type="text" id="textField2">
            <input type="text" id="textField">

             <select id="select" name="selectData">
                    <option value="firstName">Name</option>
                    <option value="id">Id</option>
            </select>
            <input id="filter" type="button" value="Filter">

            <script>
                    var temp = document.getElementById("textField2").value;
                    if(document.getElementById("select")[0].value === "id"){
                            temp.style.visibility = "visible";
                    }else {
                            temp.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    }
            </script>
</form>
```

There probably is a mistake somewhere or maybe there's any other (better) way to do this?

Comment: `document.getElementById("select")[0].value` should be: `document.getElementById("select").value` as `document.getElementById()` returns only one element (or `null`, if the element isn't found, or doesn't (yet) exist); there's no need for an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```html
<form>
  <script>
    function toggle() {
      var temp = document.getElementById("textField2");
    
      //check for selected option.
      if(document.getElementById("select").value === "id"){
        temp.style.visibility = "visible";
      } else {
        temp.style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
    }
  </script>
  <input class="hidden" type="text" id="textField2" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <input type="text" id="textField">
  
  <select id="select" name="selectData" onchange="toggle()">
    <option value="firstName">Name</option>
    <option value="id">Id</option>
  </select>
  
  <input id="filter" type="button" value="Filter">         
</form>
```